# jQuery: Wait for function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions in jQuery and one needs data the other is loading from a DB via php and json(this part works).
My problem is that the first one starts berfore the data is loaded.
How con I fix this?

Here a little code to understand:

```
function loadBody(){
    //Create an calendar of selectet month with classes to Events
}
function loadEvents(){
    //loads Events from DB with php and json and puts them into an array
}
```

I tryed e.g. the following:

```
function loadCal(){
    $.when(loadEvents()).done(loadBody());
}
```

Comment: Try removing the last brackets like this:  `$.when(loadEvents()).done(loadBody);`

Comment: `$.when(loadEvents()).done(loadBody);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`loadBody` not `loadBody()` : you were executing `loadBody` instead of giving the callback.

```
function loadCal(){
    $.when(loadEvents()).done(loadBody);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$when` expects a promise to be returned by the method passed into it. You need to make sure `loadEvents` method returns a promise.

```
function loadEvents(){
    return $.ajax({
        //Make ajax call to loads Events from DB
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadBody(){
    //Create an calendar of selectet month with classes to Events
}
function loadEvents(){
    //loads Events from DB with php and json and puts them into an array
    loadBody();//call here after load complete
}
function loadCal(){
  loadEvents();
}
```

Comment: And now I want to call `loadData()` after `loadEvents()` has completed... awk!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that loadEvents immediatelly returns, so loadBody is called before it finishes to load the file asynchronously. Can you post the full loadCal function? In it you'll have some callback, that saves the data to the array. There you could call loadBody(). I know it's not as nice as you tried, but it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var loadEvents = function (callback) {
   // do stuff...

   callback()
};

var loadBody = function () {
   loadEvents(function () {
      // loadEvents function is already done here...
      // continue with loadBody function
   })
};
```